# Set Authentication while DeviceAdmin mode get disable?

Tags: java, android

I am create an parental control app, where i want to put the Simple password authentication before disable to administrator mode by used . I am using DeviceAdminReceiver . An Idea or sample code which help . Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no direct approach to achieve it. However there  is a workaround which can be done by overriding [onDisableRequested()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html#onDisableRequested(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) method of DeviceAdminReceiver

```
public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        DevicePolicyManager mDPM =(DevicePolicyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService("device_policy");
        mDPM.lockNow();
        // You can also display overlay screen
        return "Are you sure you want to disable the Device admin?";//OR whatever message you would like to display
    }

}
```

As per documentation

> Called when the user has asked to disable the administrator, as a result of receiving ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED, giving you a chance to present a warning message to them. The message is returned as the result; if null is returned (the default implementation), no message will be displayed.

**Note:**

If you are trying to display overlay screen, do note that disable popup will and deactivate screen will have high visibility precedence. Any attempts to do so won't help much. One work around is to lock screen first and then display overlay screen.

Comment: This simple give dialog box which ok and cancel button, I want my own UI will open when onDisableRequested is called, so i can authenticate used.

Comment: @rahulchaube you have a small window to do something before you return the value. You can either lock the device as I have shown in the answer or create a overlay view to cover entire screen

Comment: This simple give dialog box which ok and cancel button, I want my own UI will open when onDisableRequested is called, so i can authenticate used.

Comment: @rahulchaube did you try the code? You can also start an activity instead of `lockNow()`. But if the kid is smart is will toggle the screen using home button and by pass your "Dialog".

Comment: i have tried , i want to handle that senario if user not give proper input (PIN), then manage to stop disable admin mode.

Comment: @rahulchaube Unfortunately you cannot do that. The best you can do is to implement the approach that I have highlighted. No app can have this privilege since it would be a big security risk. Imagine your self with an app with admin rights which cannot be disable. It could lead to various malicious usage

Comment: @rahulchaube you can start an Activity inside this method. You can try it out.

Comment: if i satart astivity still admin mode get disable, can you give code structure.